# Problems with Node.js and Selenium Webdriver installation

Tags: node.js, macos, selenium, webdriver, node-modules

I'm trying to install Selenium Webdriver on Macbook, via Node and NPM in the terminal, and have encountered a few errors during the install - some advice on a solution, or if anybody has encountered this error before would be greatly appreciated.

The error messages I've encountered are as follows:

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/henry/package.json' npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/henry/package.json' npm WARN henry No description npm WARN henry No repository field. npm WARN henry No README data npm WARN henry No license field.
```

Specifically the first error:

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/henry/package.json'
```

is one that I haven't seen much when looking up this issue in google - what would this refer to in particular?

This is the while message which I see upon pressing enter:

```
henry@Henrys-MacBook-Pro ~/SeleniumBasicsHenry $ npm install selenium-webdriver npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/henry/package.json' npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/henry/package.json' npm WARN henry No description npm WARN henry No repository field. npm WARN henry No README data npm WARN henry No license field.

selenium-webdriver@4.0.0-alpha.1 updated 1 package and audited 126 packages in 1.507s found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The next error(s) are as follows, whilst trying to install chromedriver:

```
henry@Henrys-MacBook-Pro ~ $ sudo npm install chromedriver -g /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver

chromedriver@73.0.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver node install.js

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/73.0.3683.20/chromedriver is not writable: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/73.0.3683.20' /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/73.0.3683.20/chromedriver is not writable: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/73.0.3683.20' ChromeDriver binary exists. Validating... ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017)

ChromeDriver is already available at '/tmp/73.0.3683.20/chromedriver/chromedriver'. Copying to target path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver ChromeDriver installation failed { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver' at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:752:3) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/install.js:282:10 errno: -13, syscall: 'mkdir', code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver' } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! chromedriver@73.0.0 install: node install.js npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@73.0.0 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /Users/henry/.npm/_logs/2019-04-18T19_37_54_156Z-debug.log
```

Just wondering if this is a permissions error, or something else - the above states that it's unlikely to be a problem with npm - any advice in solving this would be much appreciated,

Many Thanks!

Henry

Google search for similar errors and subsequent solutions - no luck as yet

Comment: As a result of the `<blockquotes>` the error trace logs have got word wrapped and debugging the log messages have become difficult.

Comment: Hello DebanjanB, sorry, I'll try and add a clarification to the error messages now c- still new to this, apologies if it was difficult to read

Comment: `@DebanjanB - Sorry - I'm still having trouble uploading a screenshot of the errors here (I'm pretty new to all this) - do you know how to upload photos here please?

Comment: I am afraid, I haven't worked extensively with Selenium through NodeJS else by now I would have constructed an answer. Still, if the error logs weren't wrapped up I felt it would be easier for the contributors to nail the issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB - no worries, thanks for you assistance - I did manage to get the error fixed, for a while at least... now I'm trying to figure out another one ha!